# What does CONNECTION INTERRUPTED mean?

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, crash, ipod-touch

I've developed an app which runs perfectly on iPhone 4, 4s and iPhone 5. I started getting some reports on crashes on iPod Touch 4G so today I started looking into the problem.

At one of the most memory-demanding viewcontrollers i started noticing "low memory warning" and soon after that it would crash. Thats fine, that made me investigate what causes this.

However now when i reach that particular viewcontroller I just get "CONNECTION INTERRUPTED" in the console and it crashes. Every single time. I tried restarting Xcode and the iPod Touch 4G but it still keeps coming.

What does it mean? And why didnt I experience this from the start when testing on my iPod Touch 4G?